# Left shift operator in C

Tags: c, bit-shift

Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define macro(a) a=a<<4;

main()
{
    int a = 0x59;
    printf("%x", a);
    printf("\n");
    macro(a)
    printf("%x", a);
}
```

For the above code, I am getting the below output:

```
59
590
```

Why am I not getting the below output as the left shift operation?

```
59
90
```

Comment: So could you please tell me what should i do so as to get the output as 90..i need to shift the last 4 bits to the first 4 bits adding 0's at the end.

Comment: Try changing `a` to `unsigned char` instead of `int` if you want it to be just 2 hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: Left shift by 4 is equivalent to multiplying the number by 2, 4 times. That is, 59 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 590 (base 16). Your output is correct.

Comment: #define macro(a) a=a<<4; <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< EVIL SEMICOLON. I tried writing a macro for doing that, but failed. Why not just used a <<= 4?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Left shifts do ***not*** truncate the number to fit the length of the original one. To get `90`, use:

```
(a<<4) & 0xff
```

`0x59` is an `int` and probably on your platform it has `sizeof(int)==4`. Then it's a `0x00000059`. Left shifting it by 4 gives `0x00000590`.

Also, form a good habit of using `unsigned int` types when dealing with bitwise operators, unless you know what you are doing. They have different behaviours in situations like a right shift.

Comment: Re *"in situations like a right shift"*: Do you mean left shift?

Comment: @PeterMortensen No, on right shifts the sign bit is good for surprises. ;-) Please read the standard.

Answer (score 6):

You shifted a hexadecimal number by 4 places to left so you get 590, which is correct.

You had

```
000001011001
```

shifted to left by 4 bits

```
010110010000
```

is 590 in hexadecimal

```
10010000
```

is 90 in hexadecimal, so you might want to remove `0101` as is shown [by phoeagon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15242958/1944441).

Answer (score 4):

In your printf, if you change %x to %d, you get a = 89.

And after left shifting you will get a = 1424.

Generally for decimal (base 10) numbers

```
a = a<< n  is  a = a*2^n
a = a>> n  is  a = a/2^n
```

For hexadecimal (base 16) numbers, any shift by n (left or right), can be considered, as a corresponding shift of the digits of the binary equivalent. But this depends on sizeof(int), used for a given compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You are using *int*, so you have:

```
 000001011001
```

If you shift it by 4 to the left, you get

```
010110010000
```

If you only want to have only the first 8 bits you don't have to use "int" but *unsigned char* (or *char*):

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define macro(a) a=a<<4;

main()
{
   unsigned char a=0x59;
   printf("%x",a);
   printf("\n");
   macro(a)
   printf("%x",a);
}
```

If you still want to use *int*, but only keep the first 8 bits, you can use a mask:

```
#define macro(a) a=(a<<4) & 0xFF
```

Comment: #define macro(a) a=(a<<4) & 0xFF; <<<< evil semicolon, please kill it with fire. I dont think that macro would work even if you tried. I tried, it didnt work. :|

Comment: My mistake. Sure you can't !!!!! (I guess everyone has done this mistake on time :D)

Answer (score 0):

> So could you please tell me what should I do so as to get the output
>   as 0x90? I need to **shift the last 4 bits to the first 4 bits** adding 0's
>   at the end

The only way you can shift the 4 last bit 4 bit to the left AND get it in the place of the first 4 bit is if your type have just 8 bit. Usually this is the case of  `unsigned char`, not `int`. You will get `0x90` for

```
unsigned char a=0x59;
macro(a)
```

but when using `int` the result is `0x590`
The error is not with the use of the `<<` is with the selection of the type. (or a misuse of macro?)